# AngularJS is not loading

Tags: python, html, angularjs, django, angularjs-controller

Hi people I have a html file named responsive.html. I want to use angularJS here. my resposive.html looks like this

```
<html ng-app="a">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

</head>
<title> Helooqw</title>
<body ng-controller="aA">
 {{ name }}
</body>
</html>
```

and my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('a', []);

app.controller('aA', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'Gentle lah';
}])
```

But when I load the page, i dont able to see the name there. Please help on this issue. Thanks in advance.
Attached is my directory:

[image]

Comment: Any JS console errors? Right click and [Inspect Element](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)?

Comment: I don't see any reason this shouldn't work. Unless that IE hack is doing something strange?!

Comment: i added my directory also.

Comment: there is no JS console errors.

Answer (score 0):

Added verbatim because its using django.

```
<html ng-app="a">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/app.js"></script>

</head>
<title> Heloow</title>
<body ng-controller="aA">
{% verbatim %}
 {{ name }}
{% endverbatim %}
</body>
</html>
```